# Spring Boot service layer test with SpringMockk

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockk

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using Kotlin.

I'm trying to write my unit tests at the moment, therefore I'm using Mockk and in particular springmockk.

This is my RecipeService class:

```
@Service
class RecipeService(
    private val recipeRepository: RecipeRepository,
    private val recipeMongoTemplateRepository: RecipeMongoTemplateRepository
) {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var categoryService: CategoryService

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var courseService: CourseService

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var dietService: DietService
    
    ......

}
```

My Test class looks like this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class, MockKExtension::class)
class RecipeServiceTest {

    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var recipeRepository: RecipeRepository

    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var recipeMongoTemplateRepository: RecipeMongoTemplateRepository

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var recipeService: RecipeService

    @Test
    fun test() {
        recipeService.getAll()
    }
}
```

While trying to inject mock repositories in my service I get the following issues:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'nl.whatsonthemenu.backend.recipe.RecipeServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'recipeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'nl.whatsonthemenu.backend.recipe.RecipeService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Does anyone know what the issue may be? Or how I would properly test my service layer within Spring with Mockk?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you forget to annotate with ```@Service``` your ```RecipeService```?

Comment: Nope, I do see I forgot to include it when I copied the service class in here. Will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Import` to have Spring Test generate an instance of your `RecipeService`, otherwise, there is nothing to autowire as the exception indicates:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class, MockKExtension::class)
@Import(RecipeService::class)
class RecipeServiceTest {
```